# Does SQL Server Express 2012 remote connection sends data in plaintext or encrypted?

Tags: sql-server, security, encryption, remote-connection

I have a Winforms (C#, .NET 4.0) application and I would like to connect to a remote SQL Server 2012 Express. Also I would like to send and receive data from the SQL Server to my application in an encrypted way, so that a potential hacker would not know which data is being sent and that could not tamper with data.

**Example1:**

```
my app: select * from .."  --> ENCRYPTED via network -->  "select * from .." SQL Server
```

Is there some easy way to do this, or should I also have my own Server application with which I would communicate via SSL and then locally communicate between SQL Server and my server application.

Example2:

```
my app: "select * from .."  --> ENCRYPTED via network 
     -->  "select * from .." my server app 
     --> plaintext to local SQL Server --> "select * from .."
```

I want to protect (encryption & anti tampering) all (both ways) the communication on the network.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: You should put the SQL Server behind a firewall and communicate with it using an HTTPS webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server supports SSL, see [Encrypting Connections to SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067.aspx). Both paths (from SQL to your APP and from your app to SQL) can be explicitly require to be encrypted, simply request `ENCRYPT=yes` in the connection string. Of course, you need the proper certificate trust chain to be set up (ie. purchase certificates signed by a trusted authority like [Thawte](https://www.thawte.com/), [GlobalSign](http://www.globalsign.com/) or [VeriSign](http://www.verisign.com/)).